# Difference between Adjective and Apposition

Tags: adjectives

Apposition : When one noun follows another to describe it, the noun which follows is said to be in apposition to the noun which comes before it.

Adjectives : Words that are used to describe a noun.

Aren't they both ( Adjectives and Apposition ) similar ?

Comment: To put it plainly, an appositive is a noun phrase that says something "equivalent" to the noun before it. An appositive is not an adjective, which modifies its noun. For example, in *My best friend, Mary, likes reading*, *Mary* is an appositive, i.e. *Mary* "is" *my best friend*.

Comment: Generally, an appositive defines a specific case of the noun it follows. The example given by @DamkerngT. shows this very clearly. In that example, Mary is a named instance of the more general noun "friend". Adjectives, on the other hand, *describe* the noun they modify. Again going with the example, "My best friend, Mary, likes reading," *best* is an adjective which gives more information about the noun "friend", while "Mary" is an appositive naming a specific friend for the sake of clarification.

Comment: There are further ways to modify nouns; consider noun adjuncts, determiners, and intensive pronouns for example.

Answer (score 5):

**Adjective**- a word like green, hungry, impossible, which is used when we
describe people, things, events etc. 
In numerous fixed expressions, an adjective is placed immediately after the noun it governs:

*Examples*: attorney-general, body politic, court martial.
proper.

- These are to be distinguished from cases in which an adjective just
  happens to follow the noun it governs

*Adjectives are used in connection with nouns and pronouns.*

*Examples*: a green apple; She's hungry.

=========================================================================
In the sentence - *Sir James Murray, the lexicographer, was born in Hawick.*

- The second element, the lexicographer, is **appositive** to the
  first, Sir James Murray.

*Similarly*- *The highest mountain in New Zealand, Mount Cook*, is called Aorangi by the Maoris.

- The second element, Mount Cook, is appositive to the first, The
  highest mountain in New Zealand.

**The appositive is not an adjective**.
In both cases the second element syntactically duplicates the first. *This is the most straightforward type of apposition
in English.*

(Reference-Fowler's Modern English Usage)

Answer (score 0):

An apposition is a noun/ noun group, after a noun, giving additional information to the first noun and separated with commas.

- 1 The capital of France, Paris, is the largest city of France.
- 2 Paris, the capital of France, is a beautiful city.

In 1 the apposition is Paris, a single noun, in 2 the apposition is the capital of France, a noun group. An appositon is always a noun/noun group, it is not an adjective.

Appositions can be derived from inserted explaining sentences which are shortened as

- 1a its name is Paris
- 2a it is the capital of France

Of course, if you call everything that modifies a noun an adjective you can easily get confused. Adjective is a word class and the term should not be used as a cover name for articles, adjectives, relative clauses and appositions, which all modify a noun.If you need a cover name you could use noun modifier or attribute (the Latin term), I use subelement to a noun.

Answer (score 0):

There is such a thing as an appositive adjective. 
In the clause, "John was a big boy, tall and strong, the adjectives "tall" and "strong" are appositive adjectives.